# mod_access for lighttpd causes a 403 error for all POST requests

Tags: debian, http, httpd, lighttpd

I have found on my debian server that running the lighttpd module `mod_access` is causing the server to response with a `403` to all `POST` requests.

It's very odd as I have two servers, one is running as I'd expect and the other keeps returning these `403`'s. They are running identical configs for lighttpd and php.

My lighttpd.conf is: https://gist.github.com/4269500

There is also one other custom conf: https://gist.github.com/4269508

I've opened up the servers for requests until I get this fixed, the server that works is `http://mercury.isitup.org/` and the one that fails is `http://venus.isitup.org/`.

After working out that disabling `mod_access` resolves the problem I greped all my lighttpd configs for uses of it ([docs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModAccess)).

Disabling each line I found didn't help, leading me to think this is perhaps some default behaviour (or bug?)...

Has anyone come across this before or know what configuration value I've got wrong?

#### Versions

> ```
>   Debian: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze)
> Lighttpd: lighttpd/1.4.28 (ssl)
>      PHP: PHP 5.3.19-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
> ```

#### Cross-Post on the Lighttpd Forum

> http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/5431

### Resolution

Using `lighttpd -p -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and finding the old values still being loaded. Turned out there was no syslinks but full files instead in conf-enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lighttpd -p -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` to verify the config looks like you want it to.

Comment: Indeed as pointed out on the forums, using this showed I was not using syslinks in the conf-enabled directory. :|